# How to select one Checkbox in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make Checkbox select only one option, I tried searching for solution but no success, so I have to use if statement to do it and it works but sometimes lags and crashes the application, if you If there is a better solution, please help me

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:dotted_border/dotted_border.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/foundation/key.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:loviser/modules/post/free_post/create_free_post.dart';
import 'package:loviser/pages/job_type_problem_page.dart';
import 'package:loviser/pages/post_to_find_page.dart';
import 'package:loviser/utils/color.dart';
import 'package:loviser/utils/utils.dart';
import 'package:loviser/values/app_color.dart';

class RowContent {
  bool isSelected = false;
  String iconLeadingURL;
  String content;
  Function itemFunction;
  RowContent(
      {required this.isSelected,
      required this.iconLeadingURL,
      required this.content,
      required this.itemFunction});
}

int count1 = 0;
int count0 = 0;
bool isFreePost = true;
final allRowContent = [
  RowContent(
      isSelected: false,
      iconLeadingURL: 'assets/images/free.png',
      content: 'Đăng bài nhờ cộng đồng hỗ trợ miễn phí',
      itemFunction: (ctxRoot) {
        print('chose to post free');
      }),
  RowContent(
      isSelected: false,
      iconLeadingURL: 'assets/images/PosttoFindFreelancers.png',
      content: 'Đăng bài tìm freelancer tư vấn',
      itemFunction: (ctxRoot) {
        print('chose post find');
      }),
];

List<RowContent> selectedContent = [];

class PostOption extends StatefulWidget {
  const PostOption({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PostOption> createState() => _PostOptionState();
}

class _PostOptionState extends State<PostOption> {
  Widget itemSwitch(RowContent item, Widget flutterSwitch) {
    return ListTile(
      tileColor: Colors.white,
      shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
      leading: Image(image: AssetImage(item.iconLeadingURL)),
      title: Text(
        item.content,
        style: const TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'AvertaStdCY-Semibold',
            fontSize: 12,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
      ),
      trailing: Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(24, 0, 0, 0),
          height: 30,
          width: 30,
          child: FittedBox(child: flutterSwitch)),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context);
    final isLandscape = mediaQuery.orientation == Orientation.landscape;
    final bool keyboardIsOpen = MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom != 0;
    final PreferredSizeWidget appBar = AppBar(
        elevation: 0.0,
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFF9F9F9),
        leading: Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(24, 0, 0, 0),
          child: IconButton(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 8, 8, 8),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            onPressed: () {
              print('Exit Job Type Freelancer page');
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            icon: const Image(image: AssetImage('assets/images/close.png')),
          ),
        ));

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFFFAFAFD),
      appBar: appBar,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
        child: Column(
            //crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Center(
                child: Container(
                  child: Column(
                    children: const <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        'LOVISER',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Color(0xFF356899),
                            fontSize: 22,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 7),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                        child: Text(
                          'Chọn giải pháp để tư vấn về vấn đề tình cảm của bạn!',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Color(0xFF0D0D26),
                              fontSize: 20,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 10),
              for (int i = 0; i < allRowContent.length; i++) ...[
                const SizedBox(height: 7),
                Column(
                  children: [
                    ListTile(
                      tileColor: Colors.white,
                      shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
                      leading: Image(
                          width: 32,
                          height: 31,
                          image: AssetImage(allRowContent[i].iconLeadingURL)),
                      title: Text(
                        allRowContent[i].content,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                            color: Color(0xff0D0D26),
                            fontFamily: 'AvertaStdCY-Semibold',
                            fontSize: 15,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w100),
                      ),
                      trailing: allRowContent[i].isSelected
                          ? Checkbox(
                              activeColor: Colors.red,
                              shape: const CircleBorder(),
                              side: const BorderSide(
                                  width: 1, color: Color(0xFFCACBCE)),
                              value: allRowContent[i].isSelected,
                              onChanged: (value) {
                                setState(() {
                                  allRowContent[i].isSelected =
                                      !allRowContent[i].isSelected;
                                  if (allRowContent[1].isSelected ==
                                          allRowContent[0].isSelected &&
                                      count1 >= count0) {
                                    allRowContent[0].isSelected == true;
                                    allRowContent[1].isSelected = false;
                                  }
                                  if (allRowContent[1].isSelected == true) {
                                    allRowContent[1].isSelected == true;
                                    allRowContent[0].isSelected = false;
                                    if (count1 == 1) {
                                      count1 = 0;
                                      count0 = 0;
                                    }
                                    count1++;
                                  }
                                  if (allRowContent[0].isSelected == true) {
                                    allRowContent[0].isSelected == true;
                                    allRowContent[1].isSelected = false;
                                    if (count0 == 1) {
                                      count1 = 0;
                                      count0 = 0;
                                    }
                                    count0++;
                                  }
                                });
                              },
                            )
                          : Checkbox(
                              activeColor: Colors.red,
                              shape: const CircleBorder(),
                              side: const BorderSide(
                                  width: 1, color: Color(0xFFCACBCE)),
                              value: allRowContent[i].isSelected,
                              onChanged: (value) {
                                setState(() {
                                  allRowContent[i].isSelected =
                                      !allRowContent[i].isSelected;
                                  if (allRowContent[1].isSelected ==
                                          allRowContent[0].isSelected &&
                                      count1 >= count0) {
                                    allRowContent[0].isSelected == true;
                                    allRowContent[1].isSelected = false;
                                  }
                                  if (allRowContent[1].isSelected == true) {
                                    allRowContent[1].isSelected == true;
                                    allRowContent[0].isSelected = false;
                                    if (count1 == 1) {
                                      count1 = 0;
                                      count0 = 0;
                                    }
                                    count1++;
                                  }
                                  if (allRowContent[0].isSelected == true) {
                                    allRowContent[0].isSelected == true;
                                    allRowContent[1].isSelected = false;
                                    if (count0 == 1) {
                                      count1 = 0;
                                      count0 = 0;
                                    }
                                    count0++;
                                  }
                                });
                              },
                            ),
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          allRowContent[i].isSelected =
                              !allRowContent[i].isSelected;
                          if (allRowContent[1].isSelected ==
                                  allRowContent[0].isSelected &&
                              count1 >= count0) {
                            allRowContent[0].isSelected == true;
                            allRowContent[1].isSelected = false;
                          }
                          if (allRowContent[1].isSelected == true) {
                            allRowContent[1].isSelected == true;
                            allRowContent[0].isSelected = false;
                            if (count1 == 1) {
                              count1 = 0;
                              count0 = 0;
                            }
                            count1++;
                          }
                          if (allRowContent[0].isSelected == true) {
                            allRowContent[0].isSelected == true;
                            allRowContent[1].isSelected = false;
                            if (count0 == 1) {
                              count1 = 0;
                              count0 = 0;
                            }
                            count0++;
                          }
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
              const SizedBox(height: 10),
              const SizedBox(height: 10),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 20, 0, 0),
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  child: TextButton(
                    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                      backgroundColor: const Color(0xffEC1C24),
                      minimumSize: const Size(327, 56),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () => {
                      allRowContent[0].isSelected
                          ? _showModalBottomSheetForFreePost()
                          : Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => PostToFind()),
                            ),
                    },
                    child: const Text(
                      'Tiếp tục',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'Poppins-Regular',
                        fontSize: 16,
                        color: Color(0xffffffff),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ]),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _showModalBottomSheetForFeePost() {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
          topRight: Radius.circular(30),
        ),
      ),
      context: context,
      builder: (builder) {
        final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
        final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
        return Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
              topRight: Radius.circular(100.0),
            ),
          ),
          height: height * 0.32,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              const Icon(Icons.remove, size: 40),
              SizedBox(
                width: width * 0.8,
                child: const Text(
                  "Bạn đang gặp vấn đề về chuyện tình cảm? xxx",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xFF150B3D),
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 24,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: height * 0.01,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: width * 0.6,
                child: const Text(
                  "Đăng vấn đề của bạn và nhờ một freelancer có kinh nghiệm tư vấn!",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: height * 0.05,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 50,
                width: 315,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).push(
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (_) => const PostOption(),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    primary: Colors.red,
                  ),
                  child: const Text(
                    "Đăng vấn đề",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  void _showModalBottomSheetForFreePost() {
    print('222');
    Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (_) => const CreateFreePost(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Please help me

Thanks for your contributions!

Comment: If you want to select or deselect one checkbox  it will make sense but for multi better use radio buttons

Answer (score 4):

Checkboxes aren't meant to be used that way.  You want [a RadioButton](https://m2.material.io/components/radio-buttons).

Answer (score 2):

if you issue is that whenever you select one check all other are selected then you should have unique isSelected variable for all the checkboxes like checkbox1 has the isSelectedFirst value and second checkbox has isSelectedSecond value in their onChanged function.